# Configuring PyQt5, fatal error U1077

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, configure

I'm trying to run the configure.py for PyQt5 from git bash, but it errors out, giving me a Fatal Error U1077. Some other people have encountered this problem, and I've been trying some of the stuff that other people have been saying, but I'm kind of new to this and it's pretty confusing.

[image: Here's what has happened so far]

The important section is "fatal error U1077: '.\cl.EXE' : return code '0x000135' " but I don't really know what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the complete steps to configure and install PyQt5 from source, you will need first to run command :

```
python configure.py
```

At this step, you did not install PyQt5, you only configured it (basically its installation dir, etc...), Do not specify your qmake path.

Next step is to source your environment variables by running in terminal :

```
"C:\Qt\Qt5.x.x\5.x\msvc2015\bin\qtenv2.bat"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
```

Replace the x by your version of Qt. Keep the double quotes, windows does not like spaces ...

Be careful to specify your Visual Studio installation. In windows, "make" is substituted by "nmake" !

the second command will change your path to Visual Studio, just stay in the same terminal and return to your PyQt5 path.

Then you run :

```
nmake
nmake install
```

You may encounter an error when you compile QtNfc. Then use :

```
python configure.py --disable QtNfc
```

and re-compile everything.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: Wait the reason I specified my qmake path is that it says the version I'm downloading requires Qt v5.0 or later. You seem to be using v4.8.7. This is because I originally downloaded 4.8, but I decided I need 5.0, how do I fix this?

Comment: Also, when I try to run the nmake.exe (from Visual Studio), it states that the "MAKEFILE not found and no target specified," sorry for the follow up questions but I'm not quite sure how to resolve this.

Comment: sourcing your Qt environment using command `"C:\Qt\Qt5.x.x\5.x\msvc2015\bin\qtenv2.bat"` should add to your PATH the correct qmake, you can verify your qmake after sourcing using `qmake -v` to see which Qt version you are using.

Comment: Ok what you can do is run qmake from Qt installation by specifying the full path to the executable `"C:\Qt\Qt5.x.x\5.x\msvc2015\bin\qmake.exe"`

Comment: So, I should run `"C:\Qt\Qt5.x.x\5.x\msvc2015\bin\qmake.exe"` and then follow the rest of the steps? It's still saying that I'm using 4.8.7.

Comment: To specify, it's still saying that after running the command, not after following the rest of the steps

Comment: we can discuss here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131298/pyqt5-configure-problem

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Git Bash to install `PyQt5` on Windows you can use the Windows command prompt. Here is a step by step guide to install `PyQt5` using `Qt5.5` on Windows (if you are interested in a newer version you just need to adapt the paths):

- Download and install [Qt5.5.1 + Mingw32](http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.5/5.5.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw492-5.5.1.exe)
- Download and uncompress [SIP](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pyqt/sip/sip-4.18.1/sip-4.18.1.zip)
- Download and uncompress [PyQt5.5.1](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pyqt/PyQt5/PyQt-5.5.1/PyQt-gpl-5.5.1.zip)

Bring up command prompt window, navigate to the uncompressed `SIP` directory, and type the following:

```
> PATH=C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin;C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin;%PATH%
> python configure.py -p win32-g++
> mingw32-make
> mingw32-make install
```

Using the same command prompt window, navigate to the uncompressed `PyQt5` directory, and type the following:

```
> python configure.py --spec win32-g++ --disable QtPositioning --no-qsci-api --no-designer-plugin --no-qml-plugin --confirm-license
> mingw32-make
> mingw32-make install
```

**NOTE #1:** that disabling QtPositioning is not really necessary, but sometime the compiler complains that it's not able to locate the `qgeolocation.h` header, so leave it disabled unless you really need it.
**NOTE #2:** To date, I was not able to compile the 5.7 version of PyQt5, not the 5.6 version (for some unexplainable errors that I couldn't solve). This is why I wrote this little installation tutorial using PyQt5.5.